# EF CORE using Script-Migration for the first migration

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core, migration

I am using visual studio 2019 and EF Core code first

I understand that is not good practice to use Migrations on the production

so what I do it is to create a script from the Migration and execute it by

for example `Script-Migration -From Old_Migrations -To New_Migrations -C MyContaxt`

the problem is I have to create a new database and this is my first Migration so I dont have the file to use in -From

What Can I do to create a script using only one Migration file or `-from {empty db} -to {my new file}`

Answer (score 0):

Use `script-migration -C YourDbContext` without `-from` and `-to`

The script makes all script from all migrations on a specific DbContext.

You have to create your database manually or add `create database YourDbName` script at the first of the script file.